# Change zero to ones in vector if surrounded by less than five consecutive zeros

Tags: r, vector, boolean, zero

I have a vector of `0`s and `1`s and want to identify the indices where a string of `0`s is surrounded by `1`s. If the number of `0`s between the `1`s is lower or equal than 5, I want to change these zeros to `1`s.

Here is an example:

```
> x <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

In positions 7,8, and 9, I have only three zeros, and thus these need to be changed to 1. The other zeros are more than 5, and thus need not to be changed.

The resulting vector should look like this:

```
> x_converted <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
```

I am doing this with a `for` loop and `if else` statement, but I am sure there must be a faster way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution with `rle` which does not change shorts sequences of zero's at the beginning or end of `x`:

```
# create the run length encoding
r <- rle(x)

# create an index of which zero's should be changed
i <- r$values == 0 & r$lengths < 5 & 
  c(tail(r$values, -1) == 1, FALSE) & 
  c(FALSE, head(r$values, -1) == 1)

# set the appropriate values to 1
r$values[i] <- 1

# use the inverse of rle to recreate the vector
inverse.rle(r)
```

which gives:

```
[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: oh, I forgot there was an `inverse.rle()` function!

Comment: @BenBolker It's just a wrapper around `rep` with some tests added ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rle()` to get the runs. Then just change it based on the length of the run, excluding first run by looking at `cumprod()`.

```r
x_rle <- rle(x)

x_0 <- cumprod(x_rle$values == 0)
x_rev_0 <- rev(cumprod(rev(x_rle$values) == 0))

x_rle$values <- ifelse(
  x_rle$lengths > 5 | x_0 | x_rev_0,
  x_rle$values,
  1
)

rep(x_rle$values, x_rle$lengths)
#>  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: This answer also fails at the tail. For example with this `x <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)`, this `ifelse` changes the last 0 to 1.

Comment: Edited to provide a solution that works with that edge case.

Answer (score 2):

The `rle()` (run-length-encoding) function makes this pretty easy.

```r
x <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
r <- rle(x)
## modify values appropriately
r$values[r$values==0 & r$lengths<=5] <- 1
## convert back to full vector
x_new <- rep(r$values, r$lengths)
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

However, this still needs a little bit of adjustment for literal edge cases — this has converted the initial run of 3 zeros to 1. Perhaps

```
n <- length(r$values)
rv_int <- r$values[2:(n-1)]
rl_int <- r$lengths[2:(n-1)]
rv_int[rv_int == 0 &
       rl_int <= 5] <- 1
x_new <- rep(c(r$values[1],  rv_int, r$values[n]),
             c(r$lengths[1], rl_int, r$lengths[n]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to avoid to change the first three zeros, as these are *not* surrounded by `1`s?

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table::rleid`: `rleid` creates run-length type group id, which are used as grouping factor in `ave`. `ave` then performs a function over the groups defined by `r`.

```
r <- data.table::rleid(x)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
sub <- !r %in% c(1, max(r)) 

x[sub] <- ave(x[sub], r[sub], FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(x) <= 3 & x == 0, 1, x))
# [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, based on converting `x` to a string and then back to a numeric vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)

x %>% str_c(collapse = "") %>% 
  str_replace_all("(?<=1)0{1,5}(?=1)", \(x) str_dup("1", nchar(x))) %>% 
  str_split("") %>% flatten %>% as.numeric

#>  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

---

Or with `purrr::walk` and `rle`:

```r
library(purrr)

x <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)

z <- rle(x)

walk(1:(length(z$values)-3), 
  ~ if (all(z$values[.x:(.x+2)] == c(1,0,1)) & z$lengths[.x+1] <= 5)
     z$values[.x+1] <<- 1)

inverse.rle(z)

#>  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```